# Is the AngularJS inject method synchronous?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is the AngularJS inject method synchronous?

For example:

```
inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
     $compile = _$compile_;
     rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the `inject` method is **synchronous** (or it would be hard to manage it).

Don't forget to load the module first.

Example :

```
    module( "MyModule" );

    inject( ( $injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService ) => {
        httpBackend = $injector.get( "$httpBackend" );
    });
    httpBackend.whenGET( "http://localhost:54486/api/data" ).respond( data );
```

If it was assynchronous httpBackend would be undefined.

Note : If `inject` was asynchronous, it would return a promise.